# Update cellForRowAtIndexPath progressView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, nsobject

I have an NSObject that holds an upload. One of the properties is a fileProgress (float).

The progress is updated via a `NSURLSessionDelegateMethod` named 
`URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend`.

The upload objects are updated properly using the `taskIdentifier`.

In a different class, I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that has a `progressView`. I would like to update the `progressView` with the current *fileProgress*.

When the upload is complete in the NSObject class, the upload is removed and a delegate method is called to let delegates know there has been a change to the queue count. As uploads drop of the progress views are changed to that moment in time.

How can I pass a reference to the current cells progress view to make the `progressview` update?

I have tried adding to my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
but that doesn't seem to work.

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         cell.progressView.progress = item.fileProgress;
         cell.lblProgress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", (item.fileProgress * 100) ];
    }];
```

***I am kinda lost here. Any help?***

**Upload Item**

```
    @interface AMUploadItem : NSObject <NSCoding>
    @property float  fileProgress; //The fractional progress of the uploaded; a float between 0.0 and 1.0.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask; //A NSURLSessionUploadTask object that will be used to keep a strong reference to the upload task of a file.
@property (nonatomic) unsigned long taskIdentifier;
    @end
```

**Custom TableViewCell.h (Empty .m)**

```
@interface ItemTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblProgress;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@end
```

**Table View Controller**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _manager = [AMPhotoManager sharedManager];
    _manager.delegate = self;    

}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_manager getQueueCount];
}


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cellUpload";

    ItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ItemTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    AMUploadItem * item = [_manager listImagesInQueue][indexPath.row];

 //THIS DOENS'T WORK
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         cell.progressView.progress = item.fileProgress;
         cell.lblProgress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", (item.fileProgress * 100) ];
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

The manager class just holds an array of **AMItemUploads** and the `NSURLSessionUploadTask` delegaes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your situation, but here's what I did in a similar situation.  Passing around references to views/cells is dangerous, since transfers can time out or become stale due to a user interaction.  Instead you should pass around unique identifiers to the views/cells, and then look them up as needed to update their progress.  Users become impatient while waiting for a transfer to complete, and assume that they can delete files and other nasty things while waiting.

```
    // this is pseudo code at best
    URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
    {
          NSString *uniqueID = <something unique from your NSURLSession >

          [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
              // assuming you can get the global instance of your controller here.
              [myController updateProgress:uniqueID];

    }

- (void) updateProgress: (NSString *)uniqueID
{
              NSArray *filesDataSource = <get your dataSource here> ;
              for ( ContentTableRow *fileRow in filesDataSource )
              {            
                 if ( [fileRow.uniqueID isEqualToString: uniqueID] )
                 {
                     // update progress
                 }
              }
           }
}
```